# Restrict incoming message signature for message broker

Tags: spring-boot, rest, activemq-classic

My goal is to define some API using REST arch style and spring boot in order to store messages to activemq message broker. I would like to have REST on top of message broker to have possibility to restrict message format. Actually the main goal is to allow only messages which contains all nessessary fields inside message payload.

Could you please suggest if it is rigth way to go and if there are any alternative ways to achive the goal?

Comment: Whether or not this is the "right way to go" for your use-case is really a qualitative question that's going to elicit opinion-based answers. Such questions are off-topic here on Stack Overflow. Every use-case is different so only you can really determine what is "right" here. Furthermore, asking if there are "any alternative ways" to do the same thing is too vague. There are lots of potential ways to reach the same goal. How many ways must an answer provide to be considered "correct"? Such vague questions are also off-topic. I recommend you rephrase to ask one clear, concrete question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is a REST-to-Messaging Proxy design and can work just fine for the use case you described.

Alternatively, you could do the message inspection *in* the broker, but since this inspection sounds logic-related, it is best suited for something running outside the broker.